# Java list with index on attributes without using sql

Tags: java

Assuming I've the following class

```
public class Book {
 private String title;
 private String year;
 private String author;
}
```

I'd like to avoid using a database engine since it's living really shortly only. Yet to improve performance I'd like to answer questions like "retrieve books where author = "Foo" and year = "2022"" or just "year = 2022" efficiently (not O(n)).

When using a Map, I can specify only one key that must be fully known, e.g. year, author, or both. Then I could get a list from there. But I need to answer both questions. So I'd need a Map with Author -> Index, Year -> Index and check if an entry is in both.

Is there any other API? Like `list.addIndexOn(Book::title)`?

I need to perform lookups on field (combinations) known at coding time.

Like `books.getYear(2022).andAuthor("X")` and `books.getYear(2022)` and `books.getAuthor("X")`.
So I can say in advance I'd need an index on year and author.

Comment: If you want to support complex arbitrary queries you're unlikely to find anything like this. Do you even need to beat linear speed? How many items do you have? If you have some restrictions on what keys can be used to do your most important filters, you can use existing data structures

Comment: @Dici Not arbitrary but specific fields (+ combinations) being sorted. Known at coding time. But since there are multiple fields, I cannot only have one sort order, but multiple. Simplest use-case would be "get all with author equals" AND "get all with year equals". If I sort by author, I can't answer year quickly. If I want author + year, it would be O(log n) + O(n) of the returned subset. If I use multiple lists, I've to keep them in sync, and store the index to compare subsets.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to support just those two types of queries, you can use a `Map<String, Map<String, Set<Book>>>` where the first key is the year and the second is the author. That's the equivalent of a Guava `Table`.

This would look like this (incomplete code):

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Set<Book>>> booksByYearAndAuthor;

// books where author = "Foo" and year = "2022"
booksByYearAndAuthor.get("2022").get("author") // add necessary null checks or default value

// books where year = "2022"
booksByYearAndAuthor.get("2022").values().stream().flatMap(...).collect(...) // add necessary null checks or default value
```

If you need to support arbitrary queries... I don't think you can get away from linear queries without implementing something yourself to add secondary indices, at the cost of extra memory. Do you have enough items to require doing this? That's the question, and if you don't need a DB I would say: probably not.

Comment: Assume it's a "dumb" worker fetching millions of entries from a service without any filtering. I don't need to persist it, and `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `DELETE` seems like a weird pattern just for that.

Comment: In your example I'd need 2-3 maps to do the query (like if I only have author and not year), else I'd have to fetch all years and then check for the authors), right?

Comment: I thought from your question that you wanted only 2 types of queries. The more types you'll require, the more likely you cannot do it without extra memory (maps) or faster than linear time. If you list all your types of queries I can try to think about it ^^

Answer (score 1):

Doing it yourself is quite hard, and puts you back in time in COBOL and navigational databases. Before investigating much time and effort in such a side-track, the following alternatives.

### 1. No indexing

Say you have 2000 books and 4 fields.

- Reading probably takes some time.
- Filling indexes takes long too, and you might need not 4 indexes, but compound indexes. In fact you do not know in advance which indexes need to be used.

So if you store the indexes with the table data, the reading takes time.

In fact it might be advisable to forget about indexes (like HashMap).
One very expressive form would be the `Stream<Book>`

```
List<Book> books = ...
books.parallelStream()
    .filter(b -> b.getYear() == 2022)
    .filter(b -> b.getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
    .sort(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle)
    .forEach(b -> System.out.println(b));
```

### 2. An embedded database

An H2 database is really simple to create, and has several advantages, as versatile (SQL) queries and indexing. Also O/R mapping in the form of JPA, like with eclipseLink is easy. Then you have the (type-safe) criteria API.

Comment: Yeah agreed, I didn't mention an embedded database as I wasn't sure about the performance, but my guess is that it's probably optimized if you have a good disk (and maybe some implementations are in-memory?)

Comment: However one thing you should clarify in your 1) is that this is linear, so it doesn't really answer the OP's question who wants to beat linear time

Comment: With sorting it is even worse. However `.parallelStream()` might (or might not) help a bit. However a `SortedMap` (like `TreeMap`) is not linear too. Just as filling a HashMap. It is a matter of number of Maps and number of coded queries.

Comment: What my answer wants to state: one is building ones own database engine for probably less than 100 (parametrizable) queries. Not necessarily faster.

Comment: Yeah I counted without sorting as I didn't know why you included a sort. I agree with you that if the number of items is low it's not even worth trying anything smart.